# How to position content perfectly within the left center of Paper component and remain that way on smaller devices?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I am putting together a component for my Goal Sharing social media app. This is what I have so far:

[image]

I'm trying to position the Avatar component as well as the two typography components beneath the Avatar component within the center of the left section of this Paper component. I have tried doing this by altering marginLeft and marginTop as you can see in the code below, but the issue when I do this is the components in this Goal component jumble on top of each other when I switch over to smaller devices. So, what's the best way to position these components in the center of the left section, and to ensure they remain that way on smaller devices?

This is the parent component file:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Moment from "react-moment";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getGoals } from "../../actions/goal";
import Spinner from "../layout/Spinner";
import Navbar from "../dashboard/Navbar";
import ThumbUpAltIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ThumbUpAlt";
import ThumbDownAltIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ThumbDownAlt";
import ChatIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Chat";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import DoneIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Done";
import {
  Typography,
  Container,
  CssBaseline,
  makeStyles,
  Grid,
  Card,
  Avatar,
  CardContent,
  CardActions
} from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(2, 0, 2)
  },
  form: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(5)
  },
  cardGrid: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(4),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(4)
  },
  card: {
    height: "100%",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  cardContent: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  profileHeader: {
    textAlign: "center",
    marginBottom: 10
  },
  avatar: {
    width: theme.spacing(10),
    height: theme.spacing(10),
    marginLeft: "2.5vw",
    marginTop: "5vh"
  },
  name: {
    textAlign: "center",
    marginLeft: "2vw"
  },
  goalText: {
    marginTop: "5vh",
    marginLeft: "3vw"
  },
  postedOn: {
    marginLeft: "2vw"
  }
}));

const Goals = ({ getGoals, auth, goal: { goals, user, loading } }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getGoals();
  }, [getGoals]);

  const classes = useStyles();

  return loading ? (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
        <CssBaseline />
        <div className={classes.paper}>
          <Spinner />
        </div>
      </Container>
    </>
  ) : (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Navbar />
      <main>
        <Container className={classes.cardGrid} maxWidth="md">
          <Typography variant="h2" className={classes.profileHeader}>
            Goals
          </Typography>
          <Grid container spacing={4}>
            {goals.map(singleGoal => (
              <Grid item key={singleGoal._id} xs={12}>
                <Card fullwidth="true" className={classes.card}>
                  <Grid container spacing={2}>
                    <Grid item>
                      <Avatar
                        className={classes.avatar}
                        src={singleGoal.avatar}
                      />
                      <Typography variant="subtitle2" className={classes.name}>
                        {singleGoal.first_name} {singleGoal.last_name}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography
                        variant="caption"
                        className={classes.postedOn}
                      >
                        Posted on{" "}
                        <Moment format="MM/DD/YYYY">{singleGoal.date}</Moment>
                      </Typography>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm container>
                      <Grid item xs container direction="column" spacing={2}>
                        <Grid item xs>
                          <Typography
                            className={classes.goalText}
                            variant="body1"
                            gutterBottom
                          >
                            {singleGoal.text}
                          </Typography>
                          <Typography variant="h5"></Typography>
                        </Grid>
                      </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                  <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}></CardContent>
                  <CardActions>
                    <ThumbUpAltIcon />
                    <Typography variant="caption">
                      {singleGoal.likes.length}
                    </Typography>
                    <ThumbDownAltIcon />
                    <Link to={`/goal/${singleGoal.user}`}>
                      <ChatIcon />
                    </Link>

                    <Typography variant="caption">
                      {singleGoal.comments.length}
                    </Typography>
                    {!auth.loading && singleGoal.user === auth.user._id && (
                      <DoneIcon />
                    )}
                    {!auth.loading && singleGoal.user === auth.user._id && (
                      <DeleteIcon />
                    )}
                  </CardActions>
                </Card>
              </Grid>
            ))}
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

Goals.propTypes = {
  getGoals: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  goal: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  goal: state.goal,
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getGoals })(Goals);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
card: {
    height: "100%",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
```

Comment: That didn't give me the desired outcome. Thanks for the answer though.